# pictorial illustration of simplicial complexes

Tags: combinatorics, commutative-algebra, simplicial-complex

Consider the following two complexes (Bruns&Herzog p.215):

[image]

By just looking at the complex on the left, i am not sure
how to read its faces. Surely its vertices are $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5$. 
The fact that e.g. $v_1$
and $v_5$ are connected via an edge, leads me to believe
that $\left\{v_1,v_5\right\}$ is a face. The fact that
the triangle $\left\{v_1,v_2,v_5\right\}$ is dotted leads
me to believe that $\left\{v_1,v_2,v_5\right\}$ is another
face. But how about e.g. $\left\{v_1,v_2,v_4,v_5\right\}$?
Is this a face? Or how about $\left\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5\right\}$?
Is this a face? And how can we distinguish between the two complexes
where e.g. $\left\{v_1,v_2,v_4,v_5\right\}$ is face in the first
but it is not a face in the second?

On the other hand, by looking at the complex on the right, i can tell
that e.g. $\left\{u_2,u_4,u_5\right\}$ is not a face.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they are not faces: 
 if $\left\{v_1,v_2,v_4,v_5\right\}$ be a face there was a pyramid ($\left\{v_1,v_4\right\}$ is missing). 
 $\left\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5\right\}$ being a face can not be shown in a picture, because it is of dimension 4.
 the complex on the right: $\left\{u_2,u_4,u_5\right\}$ is not a face

Comment: $\left\{u_4,u_5\right\}$ is not in complex, for example

Answer (score -1):

USe the definiton of simplicial complex to read the faces. A simplex S of $k+1$ point say $p_i$ is the affine combination with non negative coefficient $\alpha_i$. A face is a subsimplex that is $T\subset S$. Convex hull of T is a simplex that is $\alpha_i=0$ if $p_i$ does not belong to T. 
    Definiton: A Simplicial complex is a finite collection  K of simplex such that
1) $\sigma\in K$ and $\tau\leq\sigma$ ($\tau$ is a subsimplex of $\sigma$)implies 
$\tau\in K$, and 
2) $\sigma$,$\upsilon\in K$implies $\sigma\cap\upsilon\leq\sigma,\upsilon$.